# Add class to even elements when even element is clicked and add class to odd elements when odd element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to add a class to the even elements when an even element is clicked and add class to the odd elements when a odd element is clicked.

I have tried using :nth-child(even) :nth-child(odd) but i cant seem to figiure out how to tell if the element clicked is even or odd.

COnsider this basic HTML

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
    <li>four</li>
    <li>five</li>
    <li>six</li>
    <li>seven</li>
    <li>eight</li>
</ul>
```

If you click on 'two', the element two, four, siz and eight should be highlighted. If you click one, the elements one, three, five and seven should be highlighted. (when i say highlighted, i might just add a class :

```
.red {
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: `red` is a bad class name. At some point you'll probably want to change the highlight color and you end up with something like `.red { background: blue; }`

Comment: By odd and even are you referring to the actual text value of your list item? Or simply their index in the list? So if the first item was "two" would that still count as odd? What didn't work with `:nth-child(even) :nth-child(odd)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/V7T7J/)

```
$("#list > li").on("click",function(){
    $('.red').removeClass('red');
    if($(this).index() % 2 == 0) {
       $('#list > li:even').addClass('red');
    } else {
       $('#list > li:odd').addClass('red');
    }
});
```

Use `$(this).index() % 2 == 0` to figure out whether the element clicked is even or odd. Then just add the class respectively using [`:even`](https://api.jquery.com/even-selector/)/[`:odd`](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/).

Comment: Thanks. This works in your example but not on my website. any ideas?

Comment: @Greg4Hughes may be you should wrap this code in doc ready handler and load the jQuery before this script.

Comment: my bad. I forgot to include jQuery. It works as i need it now. thanks again!

Comment: I have another question though. Should I ask here or make a new question?

Comment: Better to ask in other if that relates to it you can ask it here.:)

Answer (score 0):

simply do this:

```
$('#list li').click(function(){
    $('#list li').removeClass('red'); // remove the red class first
    ($(this).index() % 2 === 0) ? $('#list li:even').addClass('red') : $('#list li:odd').addClass('red');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Without jQuery.

```
(function() {
  var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("#list li");
  for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
    setup(nodes[i],i); 

  function setup(node, index) {
    node.addEventListener("click", function() {
        for (var j = 0; j < nodes.length; j++) {
            nodes[j].classList.remove("red");
            if (index % 2 === 0 && j % 2 === 0 ||index % 2 === 1 && j % 2 === 1) {
                nodes[j].classList.add("red");
            }
        }
    });
  }
}());
```