# Toggle slide element up if not clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I just had help with my first question: [Add class to even elements when even element is clicked and add class to odd elements when odd element is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23586027/add-class-to-even-elements-when-even-element-is-clicked-and-add-class-to-odd-ele)

Here is my next question: look at the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VHd6k/

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>
        <p class="title">One</p>
        <p class="summary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vulputate felis in turpis sodales ullamcorper. Morbi condimentum odio nec auctor iaculis</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="title">Two</p>
        <p class="summary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vulputate felis in turpis sodales ullamcorper. Morbi condimentum odio nec auctor iaculis</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="title">Three</p>
        <p class="summary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vulputate felis in turpis sodales ullamcorper. Morbi condimentum odio nec auctor iaculis</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="title">Four</p>
        <p class="summary">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vulputate felis in turpis sodales ullamcorper. Morbi condimentum odio nec auctor iaculis</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQUery:

```
$("#list > li .title").on("click", function () {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    if ($(this).parent().index() % 2 == 0) {
        $('#list > li:even').addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('#list > li:odd').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

my question: the active class is added as I want. How do I get the other li to slide up when they aren't being click? In order words, only one shoudl be expanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest answer would seem to be to slide all the others with `$('.summary').not($(this).next()).slideUp();`:

```
$("#list > li .title").on("click", function () {
    $('.summary').not($(this).next()).slideUp();
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    if ($(this).parent().index() % 2 == 0) {
        $('#list > li:even').addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('#list > li:odd').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/VHd6k/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after the slideToggle:

```
$('#list > li .title').not(this).next().slideUp();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use focusout.

```
$("#list > li .title").on("focusout", function (){
    $(this).slideToggle();
});
```